# Dynamic Creation of Editors - Does Browser need to exit the function to make the changes?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to dynamically create and destroy TinyMCE editors like this .
1) It appears that if I put a break point and check for tinymce editors after creation , i.e after the first for loop - I dont see them in the Browser 
2) Nor do I see them in tinymce.editors in console

Hence my destroy is not working . However after everything , I can see the editors .
Because the second for loop won't get executed .

Question mainly is , is there something like function has to exit and then browser makes the DOM changes ? If so should I put a sleep ? I got this idea from 
[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep) i.e Browser makes DOM changes after the function exists or something like that .
Can anyone enligthen me ?

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) 
    {
    //i=0;
    divObj = document.createElement('div');
    divObj.className = 'top_div';
    divObj.id = 'top_div_' + i;
    divObj.innerHTML = 'Tiny Editor';
    var textareaObj = document.createElement('textarea');
    textareaObj.className = 'simpleEdit';
    textareaObj.id = 'nic_' + i;
    textareaObj.style.cssText="width: 300px; height: 100px;";
    divObj.appendChild(textareaObj);
    document.body.appendChild(divObj);
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, textareaObj.id);
    }
    editors = tinyMCE.editors.length;

   for (var i=0;i<editors;i++)
   {
     tinyMCE.remove(tinyMCE.editors[0]);
    }
```

Comment: window.setTimeout(destroy,2000) would solve this problem . TinyMCE apparently needs some time for the editors to show up in the browser , so we need to call the destroy after some time .

Comment: this depends on your client machiene - it won't work on an old and slow PC

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the remove function right after you create the editors. Thus, your editor instances have not been fully created - which is the reason for you not finding any instances.
The right way here is to use the tinymce [init config param onInit](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3aoninit), which gets called when the editor is ready.